# how to assign Richfaces Panel Bar with image as label

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, richfaces

I am having  a set  of panelbar Items  which  need to have a  image  as  label  and  this  image  will  change   when  onexpand and  shrunck of the panel .

please help  me in  resolving  this  issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any such options from [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/panelBar.jsf?tab=info&cid=613405), But you can always play with raw HTML and set image there.

Answer (score 0):

First, define two CSS classes: one for the normal state (I call it `panelBarClosed`), the second one for the opened state (`panelBarOpened`), and [set the image as the background](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp):

```
.panelBarClosed {
  background: url('/path/to/images/closed.png');
}
.panelBarOpened {
  background: url('/path/to/images/opened.png');
}
```

Now, on your `<rich:panelBarItem>`, set the first class:

```
<rich:panelBarItem headerClass="panelBarClosed" headerClassActive="panelBarOpened">
    ...
</rich:panelBarItem>
```

I am not sure if this is enough or not (I am not able to test it right now).

If this still is not working, this component provides two other attributes that can be useful in your case: `onenter` and `onleave`. The first event is fired when you "enter" the panel bar item (i.e. you open it), the second one when you leave it. So the idea is to change the CSS class of the component on this events:

```
<rich:panelBarItem ...
    onenter="jQuery(this).removeClass('panelBarClosed').addClass('panelBarOpened');"
    onleave="jQuery(this).removeClass('panelBarOpened').addClass('panelBarClosed');">
    ...
</rich:panelBarItem>
```

(again, I didn't test it, so maybe this solution should be corrected a little)